# I'm working on macbook air m2 and this message appears when i try to run the testing flutter app

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm working on macbook air m2 and this message appears when i try to run the emulator testing flutter app. i just want to make sure that it works before i begin working on my project.

[image]

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/ahmed/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/ahmed/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

After running this command:  $ sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license, the problem appears to have been fixed.